# "SDK does not contains any platforms" in Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: java, android

When I had Windows 7, there were no problems but after installing Windows 10, Android Studio does not want to finish the installation, because "SDK does not contain any platforms", please help me fix this problem.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMoH1.png]

Comment: This is not a correct path for sdk,Where did you install sdk?

Comment: What about Local disk C then Android then SDK is it not there?

Comment: This solved for me: close this page. open a new project then you see an error for SDK missing. click on it and install sdk from google site again. (Note: I have a problem to connect to google therefor I forced to use VPN)